# how to make a if statement print a string for every time a character is in an input

Tags: python, if-statement

Ok so I am making a program in python that converts whatever someone inputs to a number code where a is 1 b is 2 so on and so forth. this is what my code looks like to start

```
print("input a message you would like to be converted to a number code")
inpi = input("")


if " " in inpi:
  print("")
if "a" in inpi:
    print("1.",end = "")
if "b" in inpi:
  print("2.",end = "")
```

the problem is if a character is in the input more than once it will only print its corresponding number once so for example if you input abab it only prints 1.2 not 1.2.1.2. Im guessing this is a pretty easy fix hopefully i'm not super skilled in python but im trying my best any help is appreciated
keep in mind that the indents and lines are in order in my code but for some reason come up weird here.

Comment: You need to iterate over every character in the string… `for c in inpi: if c == 'a': ...`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're probably going to have a lot of letters to provide codes for, I suggest setting up a dict that maps the letters to the codes:

```
cipher = {
    "a": "1.",
    "b": "2.",
    # other cipher mappings go here
}
```

and then using the dict to convert the input into a coded string:

```
print("input a message you would like to be converted to a number code")
inpi = input("")
print("".join(cipher.get(c, "") for c in inpi))
```

If the cipher follows the same pattern all the way up to `z -> 26.`, you can simply generate it in a loop using `chr` and `ord` rather than typing it all out:

```
>>> cipher = {chr(i + ord("a")): f"{i+1}." for i in range(26)}
>>> cipher
{'a': '1.', 'b': '2.', 'c': '3.', 'd': '4.', 'e': '5.', 'f': '6.', 'g': '7.', 'h': '8.', 'i': '9.', 'j': '10.', 'k': '11.', 'l': '12.', 'm': '13.', 'n': '14.', 'o': '15.', 'p': '16.', 'q': '17.', 'r': '18.', 's': '19.', 't': '20.', 'u': '21.', 'v': '22.', 'w': '23.', 'x': '24.', 'y': '25.', 'z': '26.'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.translate`.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

trans = str.maketrans({c: f'{i}.' for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)})    
print('abba'.translate(trans)) # 1.2.2.1.
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple but perhaps not the most elegant solution would be to use a dictionary. You could have a dictionary like this one:

```
mydict = {"a":"1", "b":"2", ..., "z":"26"}
```

If you prefer not writing it out manually, you can do the following to let Python handle it for you:

```
mydict = dict(([letter for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"][i-1], str(i)) for i in range(1,27))
```

Finally, all you need to do is iterate through the string and pass each letter through the dictionary

```
mydict = dict(([letter for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"][i-1], 
str(i)) for i in range(1,27))
originalString = "example"
finalString = ""
for letter in originalString:
    finalString += (mydict[letter] + ".")
print(finalString)
```

In short, what you're doing is creating a dictionary which effectively acts like a real world dictionary where you convert a string into another string (though in Python it can be something other than a string). We're taking "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and turning it into a list, then assigning a numerical value starting at 1 that increments. Once that's done, the for loop checks what the numerical value given to each letter is then adds that to the finalString. Finally, we print this finalString. For example, the above program returns 5.24.1.13.16.12.5. for the word "example". Though keep in mind this dictionary only works with lowercase letters, so you might want to convert the string into lowercase letters by doing

```
originalString = originalString.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through the input-string, then, instead of testing every letter, you might use the `ord` function, which returns the ASCII-code of a character.

Answer (score 0):

here is answer to your problem

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
while True:
    user_input = input("input a message you would like to be converted to a number code: ")
    print(".".join([str(letters.index(letter)+1) for letter in user_input]) + ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("input a message you would like to be converted to a number code")
inpi = input()

print(".".join(list(map(lambda a: str(ord(a) - 96), inpi))))
```

Changing string to ascii, then converitng to string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

k={j:str(i) for i,j in enumerate(ascii_lowercase,1)}
x1=input("Enter string: ")
print("Translation: "+''.join(k[x.lower()] for x in x1))
```

basically, use a dictionary comprehension to make a dictionary, then use `join` to join the elements of the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing multiple if...else blocks you should use the dictionary data structure.

[A starting point for Python Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

So your code will look like this

```py
convert_map = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

user_input = input()

converted = ''

# If element key in convert_map then use the value else value is ''
for elem in user_input:
    converted = converted + str(convert_map.get(elem, ''))

print(converted)
```